# No reverse match error while using Jquery with Django . How to debug?

Tags: jquery, django

I am on the learning phase of django and have encountered a weird bug while doing so .

I am using Jquery to supply the front end with the list of users registered .

My template looks something like this

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Userbase</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/media/js/autocomplete.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/jquery-1.2.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/dimensions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/autocomplete.js"></script>
    {% block extra_css %}{% endblock extra_css %}
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( '#searchSubmit' ).click( function() {
        q = $( '#q' ).val();
        $( '#results' ).html( '&nbsp;' ).load(
                    '{% url userbase_user_search %}?q=' + q );
    });
});

$( document ).ajaxStart( function() {
    $( '#spinner' ).show();
}).ajaxStop( function() {
    $( '#spinner' ).hide();
});
</script>
<label for="">Users: </label>
<input type="text" id="UserSearchField" name="UserSearchField">
```

My views look something like this

```
def ajax_user_search( request ):
    if request.is_ajax():
        q = request.GET.get( 'q' )
        if q is not None:
            results = User.objects.filter(
                Q( first_name__contains = q ) |
                Q( last_name__contains = q ) |
                Q( username__contains = q ) ).order_by( 'username' )

            template = 'usersearch.html'
            data = {
                'results': results,
            }
            return render_to_response( template, data,
                context_instance = RequestContext( request ) )
```

I would be honest , that I got the small jquery code from another code base . So finding it a bit problematic to make it work here . Any help would be much appreciated . All I want is a text field which when clicked , (when the cursor comes on ) , gives a pull down of all the users present in the db .

Any help would be much appreciated . Any tutorial links to understanding jquery would be good too .

Edit:

```
This is my urls.py


from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib import databrowse
from world.views import welcome 
from openmaps.views import *
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', welcome),
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^databrowse/(.*)', databrowse.site.root),
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>. *)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
       'document_root': 'q:\projects\cape\static', 'show_indexes': True}),

   url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')),
   url(r'^userbase/','userbase.views.PermLayer',name='usersearch'),
)
```

That is how it looks like now . PermLyaer is one of the classes of the view .

Comment: Can you also show your urls.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% url userbase_user_search %}
```

That gets the url with the name userbase_user_search but you don't have a url with that name.

Comment: If ajax_user_search is a class in the view , then what should the url be that maps onto both ajax_user_search and PermLayer .

Comment: I am a bit confused here . Ajax_User_Search and PermLayer are both classes of the view userbase . How do I access both in the same template .

Comment: You can use a string which contains app.module.function. E.g. 'userbase.views.ajax_user_search'.

Comment: I did all the necessary changes but got this as error The view permissions.views.user_search didn't return an HttpResponse object.

Comment: From your view code, if it is not an Ajax request, or if `q` is None, it will not return a response. As the error says, it always needs to return an HttpResponse, even if it's an empty one, or an error/redirect.

Comment: The solution is turning out to be very tricky infact . I thought of removing all the else statement but then it gives an error as it can't process NONE . So what should I do about it ?

Comment: I did all the changes and now I am back to square one with the "reverse " error . Django can somtimes be very frustrating

Comment: Raising a 404 error when a response object can't be returned doesn't work?

Comment: The response is not a problem . The problem lies with this {% url userbase_user_search %} . How do I ask the django Templating language to only evaluate the url call at run time & not at first page load?

Comment: `url` is just a way to avoid hardcoding URLs. It tells Django to look for the actual URL in the url.py file(s). Your HTML page does contain a call to `url`, so Django *has to* look for the URL when generating the page. I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: ok lets start afresh . I want to have a text box , which when I click on to type in it , gives me a pull down menu of all the users that are registered . Thats all . What should be the jquery involved?

Comment: I would use [this plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) and return JSON from the Python function.

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to solve this issue in the same ajax application. You can simply replace the below code in index.html under your `base.html`. If you have used different name from `demo_user_search` in `urls.py` replace it with your name.

`$( '#results' ).html( '&nbsp;' ).load( "{% url 'demo_user_search' %}?q=" + q );`

or (Without quotes in `load()` function

`$( '#results' ).html( '&nbsp;' ).load( {% url 'demo_user_search' %}?q= + q );`